# How to upgrade PHP 7.2 to 7.4 in Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: updates, php, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to upgrade the default PHP version 7.2 to 7.4 in Ubuntu under WSL in Windows 10.  How do I do this?

Comment: Probably your favorite search engine! :)

Comment: From (the first thing on) [AskUbuntu's "How to ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) page -- *"Search, and research.
Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"*

Answer (score 2):

After two days of research. I upgraded my php version from 7.2 to 7.4.
As the following step:

1. Update the version of ubuntu in windows10(Linux subsystem).
2. Add line
   `deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted`
   to file `/etc/apt/sources.list`
3. `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`
4. `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`
5. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
6. `sudo apt-get install php7.4`

`php -v`
7. Install php 7.4 modules (extensions)

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-fpm libapache2-mod-fcgid php7.4-curl php7.4-dev php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-zip php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml`

`sudo a2enmod php7.4`

`service apache2 restart`

Comment: So, now you have both 7.2 and 7.4? Are you lucky enough to not have any problems with mixing these?